# Sharing music from CD's

Tags: music, sharing

Me and my husband have just upgraded our phones. Since we have done this I now can no longer access all our music (on my phone). We have separate I-Tunes accounts and family share and for the last god knows how long I have always been able to listen to Albums he has burned from CD's on to our Mac on my phone but all of a sudden I don't have access to them all. Most I can access and download from the cloud but there are the odd tracks and all albums by Garth Brooks that I can not access. Does anyone have any idea what's going on. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Prior to various iCloud services, you used iTunes to sync music to your iphone. If you burned from CDs, the music will be in iTunes on your Mac. The simplest solution is to plug in your new iphone to the Mac and let iTunes sync. This will allow you to copy all music in iTunes Mac to the new iPhone. (this also allows you to backup your phone to the mac)

Since iCloud you have the option of syncing your music library via iCloud. However, this is not a free service, you need to enable iCloud Music Library, and pay for the service.  You can get this via subscribing to Apple Music or paying for something called iTunes Match. Either of these services will allow you to stream all your music, or download to your phone from iCloud.